# Node js routes order messed up

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 node js routes that are dynamically created.

Route 1
   app.get(/search-user/:firstname)

Route 2
   app.get(/search-user/:lastname)

The values of the first and last name come from different forms when they are submitted.

The issue I am facing is that if my routes are in the order shown above then routing for Route 1 works but request for Route 2 gets redirected to Route 1 and gives undesirable results. The exact opposite occurs when I change the order. It seems that whichever order the Routes are placed only the first one ends up working.

I read the documentation about routing and the order of execution. However, nowhere it mentions order between 2 get routes that are different.

Any help is appreciated. I would like to make both routes functional irrespective of thr order.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In express the variables you used in route, `:firstname` OR `:lastname` is just a placeholder and here they both are same for express.

If you make request like **localhost:3000/search-user/nick** OR **localhost:3000/search-user/NicksLastName**, there is no way for express route to distinguish, which is what? Therefore, always the first route will be matched (it is not been redirected)

Hence, you should use something more specific like 
Route 1 `app.get(/search-user/firstname/:firstname)` AND Route 2 `app.get(/search-user/lastname/:lastname)`

Comment: Very cool. Works very well. Thanks for your assistance. I would have expected the documentation to mention that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to make 2 separate routes.
you can pass query string param in URL and you can access it below ways.

```
URL= xyz.com/?firstName=anything&lastName=12312313
URL= xyz.com/?firstName=anything
URL= xyz.com/?lastName=12312313

var id = req.query.id;

**OR**

var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```